# Is this new "pyhton" tag a typo?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Just came across this new tag [pyhton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyhton) which is most likely a typo. I did a quick search just in case and I couldn't find anything conclusive.

The only question using it is referring to python anyway:
[Error installing uwsgi with pip: "Python.h no such file". python-dev and python3-dev packages are installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59000289/1244884)

Comment: Good catch. Looks like the OP just miss-typed. I've edited to fix it.

Comment: If it's common enough a typo, it would probably be worth adding it as a "typographical" synonym. For example [`sql-server`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/synonyms) has the synonym `sql-srever`

Comment: @Larnu Shame I don't have enough score in [tag:python] to be able to suggest a synonym.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've edited it out of the question (<strike>[pending approval](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24662433)</strike> approved). The tag will automatically be removed [when the daily purge script runs](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24662433).

We don't traditionally add misspellings as tag synonyms ([python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) only has [four synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/synonyms)), so suggesting it as a synonym won't be neccesary. Thanks for pointing this out!